# How to serialize to XML / SOAP an object with property that is another complex object type? I keep getting invalid document structure

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm trying to serialize a pretty simple set of C# code to XML / SOAP. The class type that I'm trying to serialize has a single property which is another class type. I keep getting an error that the document fails in the Epilog and would create an invalid XML document. Exact error message is below ...

> Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML
> document.

Below is my test set of code ...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var mapping = new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Envelope));
        
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(mapping);
        
        var envelope = new Envelope
        {
            Body = new Body
            {
                Foo = "Testing"
            }
        };

        using (var destination = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(destination, envelope);

            var result = destination.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
    
    public class Envelope
    {
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Body
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my link to a .net fiddle page: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u0oyUo

How can I make this serialize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you using:

```
var mapping = new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Envelope));
```

Is there a specific reason for? If you skip that part and change the folling line to:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
```

It serializes the class.

Comment: Was using that because I had seen it elsewhere on SO. Your code works, though. Thanks.