# Class with nested classes throws InvalidOperationException: Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to Serialize a simple class with a single property for a SOAP request using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer which works fine, but as soon as I add another property to my class and the property type is another class I receive this error message when executing XmlSerializer.Serialize(StringWriter, myclass):

```
InvalidOperationException: Token StartElement in state Epilog would result in an invalid XML document.
```

The two classes are dead-simple:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://example.org/", ElementName = "Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I perform the serialization:

```
var foo = new Foo(Id = "foo-id", Bar = new Bar { Id = "bar-id" });
var soapReflectionImporter = new SoapReflectionImporter("http://example.org");
var xmlTypeMapping = soapReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Foo));
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(xmlTypeMapping);
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
}
```

If I remove the `Bar` property from `Foo`, everything works as expected. I already looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461431/how-to-serialize-to-xml-soap-an-object-with-property-that-is-another-complex-o) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44008900/consecutive-xml-serialization-causes-token-startelement-in-state-endrootelemen) without it solving the issue. I also cannot simply call the constructor for XmlSerializer with a type parameter because I need the XmlTypeMapping for the SOAP request. Can someone point out where the issue is or if I am missing some additional configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The output XML needs a root element. Using XmlWriter along with XmlWriterSettings can help, like below.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://example.org/", ElementName = "Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

    
public class Bar
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Foo() { Id = "foo-id", Bar = new Bar { Id = "bar-id" } };
        var soapReflectionImporter = new SoapReflectionImporter("http://example.org");
        var xmlTypeMapping = soapReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Foo));
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(xmlTypeMapping);
        //using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        //{
        //    serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
        //}

        Stream st = new MemoryStream();
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.WriteEndDocumentOnClose = true;
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(st, settings);

        writer.WriteStartElement("base");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, foo);
        writer.Close();  //will write the final closing tag

        st.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```